# What does this particular symbol mean/stand for?

Tags: endless-space

[image: EL Pic]
Sometimes my heroes show me this symbol, but I don't know what it actually means. What does this symbol stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That symbol indicates the siege strength of a fleet. When you see that message, it's saying that the siege strength of the fleet has been increased by 50%.